# c# application runs fine through visual studio but standalone exe fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

My C# application runs fine (in both Debug and Release mode) when I run it through Visual Studio 2012 or executing the .exe through Debug/Release folder, but it fails when I copy that .exe to some other location and run it. The error message that I receive is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'bms.Common, Version=5.0.0.1006,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am copying the .exe from Debug/Release folder to some folder. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Well, are you copying the .dll's as well or just the .exe?

Comment: just the .exe. How should I package .dll's and .exe within one executable ?

Comment: You don't, the .dll's need to be in the same folder as the executable. If you want an .exe on your desktop you create a shortcut to it.

Comment: "Am I doing it wrong?". It doesn't work. Clearly you're doing it wrong. You need to copy every file from the compiled folder to your final destination. You don't actually need the .pdb files, if present, they contain extra information useful during debugging or for producing better stacktraces, but all dll's, all exe's, probably all/most .config files, and if present, usually most subfolders (could be language resources).

Answer (score 1):

In Debug folder exists only .exe file? No other dlls? You should copy all .dll files from Debug folder to target directory along with .exe file.
If you want package all libraries into one executable assembly then look at ILMerge utility http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

usage:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ilmerge C:\my.exe C:\my.dll /out:C:\merged.exe

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should be deploying the DLLs in the same folder as the executable.  With .NET we don't usually compile everything into one big .exe the same way you might link a c program.

There are certain exceptions: for example, you could put the DLLs in the GAC or put them somewhere else and provide what is known as a "probing path."  Those are advanced approaches which should not be used unless you know what you're doing.

For complete information on how .NET resolves DLL references, I suggest you read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).